# No Option for New->Web application on Intellij Idea 14.1.2

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04

I have IntellijIdea14.1.2 (Community version) on Ubuntu 12.04LTS 
I am trying to create a web application project from scratch and I chose to follow this guide
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/enabling-web-application-support.html#new

But I am not getting the option mentioned in Step 3 "*Under Additional Libraries and Frameworks, select the Web Application check box.
Select the version of the Servlet specification to be supported from the Versions list.* "
Only thing I see there is Groovy. Can someone tell me what to do to enable the other options in that list? I tried looking at the facets page and even that seems to assume that there are options available which I cannot see on my client.

Similarly I cannot see the rest plug-in mentioned in this page when I search for restful https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/preparing-for-rest-development.html

I tried reinstalling IntelliJ thinking something was wrong with the installation but doesn’t seem to be the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the community version, you can only develop Java SE applications. For developing web or enterprise application, you need to buy the commercial version. Please refer this documentation to check difference between Editions

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IC

Comment: Daym!!! I think I missed reading that info somewhere there.. Thanks for the answer! Appreciate it!!